# Grails Datepicker Onchange Event

Tags: jquery, grails

I need to use the onchange event in grails datepicker,but simply using the onchange event does not work in date picker.

Here is the code:

```
<td>g:datePicker name="A"precision="month"years="${(startDate.getAt(Calendar.YEAR))..
(EndDate?.getAt(Calendar.YEAR))}"  value="${FIRst}"</td>
```

I need to add the onchange event for the above code. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do that using jquery. Because g:datepicker will break into different parts, in your case 2 selects (month and year). ie:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#A_month').live('change', function() {
 ...your code here....
});

$('#A_year').live('change', function() {
 ...your code here....
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We ran into a similar issue in our app and went with the [Calendar Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/calendar). In addition to allowing javascript onChange the user experience is much better too.
Install the plugin and use its datePicker tag like:

```
<calendar:datePicker name="myDatePicker" dateFormat="%m/%d/%Y" value='${Date.parse("MM/dd/yyyy",myHistory?.myDate)}'  onChange="setMyDate(this.value);"/>
```

If you can't use the plugin then render the g:datePicker through your own taglib, Something on the lines of:

```
def customDatePicker = {
    def dateP = g.datePicker(name:'test')
    dateP = dateP.replaceAll("<select ", "<select onChange='javascript:alert(10000)' ")
    out << dateP
}
```